# How to use IF and INTERVAL in JOOMLA query?

Tags: mysql, joomla

I update db when user pressed key inside textarea with current datetime.
In the query below, I want to check if usr has typed anything 10 seconds lesser than current time.

ERROR:

Help me to get this query right to work in JOOMLA

Answer (score 0):

All these queries have both PHP and MySQL errors (logical errors and syntax errors). The errors really have nothing to do with Joomla. Try getting your query to work on MySQL (in phpMyAdmin) and then post it back here.